# Single Line Menu Action in Eclipse RCP Workbench Coolbar

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I added a JFace action to the workbench coolbar of an RCP application using a subclass of the ActionBarAdvisor. For some reason the corresponding menu is drawn with what I guess is an extra line. It is causing the whole coolbar including the list of open perspectives to be way too tall:

[image]

Anyone know how to make it single-lined? I tried adding SWT.SINGLE style to the Action constructor, but that didn't help. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

ActionBarAdvisor.fillCoolBar() implementation:

```
protected void fillCoolBar(final ICoolBarManager coolBar) {

    final IToolBarManager toolbar = new ToolBarManager(coolBar.getStyle());
    coolBar.add(new ToolBarContributionItem(toolbar, "main"));

    toolbar.add(new Pulldown());
}
```

Action implementation:

```
public class Pulldown extends Action {

    public Pulldown() {
        super("Saved Layouts");
        setMenuCreator(menuCreator);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not direct the answer of your problem, but I would declare the button as menu extension with dropdown/radio style. Thus you don't have to change the code of the coolbar.[Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Dropdown_Command) is a tutorial about toolbar menu contributions.

```
<extension
          point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
       <menuContribution
             allPopups="false"
             locationURI="toolbar:de.example.com">
          <command
                commandId="de.abas.erp.wb.base.marker.commands.PullDownCommand"
                icon="icons/16x16/layouts.png"
                label="Saved Layouts"
                style="pulldown">
          </command>
       </menuContribution>
    </extension>
```

Comment: Using an extension point did work, thanks. For anyone who has this same problem, be advised that you have to use delegates (IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate) which can limit functionality (like fine-grained enablement control in my case).